# Does a version of the Delta Method exist for non-i.i.d. sequences?

Tags: asymptotics, iid, delta-method

I have a sequence of random variables that are non-independent, but usually identically distributed. I am wondering if a version of the Delta Method exists under the case when I only have that the data is identically distributed. If so, would there also be cases where it may hold when the sequence is neither independent nor identically distributed? Thanks.

Comment: Do you sum these non-independent variables? Are you asking for a variance calculation for such a sum - $Y$ ?

Comment: I agree with previous comment. It is not 100% clear what the question is asking. Please consider adding the mathematical details

Comment: The delta method is derived from the Taylor Series.  If they are not IID, then you get a multivariate PDE instead of a univariate ODE, and it is a little more complex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## 1

You seem to be confusing the delta method with the central limit theorem.

The delta method is *not* specifically about i.i.d. data. The delta method is more generally about variables that are approximately normally distributed (and the mean of iid distributed data is approximately normally distributed).

## 2

So the delta method may work as well with the mean of non-i.i.d. data. As long as this mean is approximately normal distributed. For that related part you need the central limit theorem.

The typical central limit theorem is formulated for i.i.d. distributed data. And independent and non identical distributed errors is entirely different and messes up everything.

When your measurements $y_i$ are dependent, then you can not use the typical models where $y_i$ are independent.

Models like [errors in variables models](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errors-in-variables_models) or [mixed effects models](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_model) are examples how to deal with correlated errors (and there are more examples).

Whether you can apply something similar as the Delta Method or the central limit theorem or a normal distribution approximation can not be said in general. But, there are certainly descriptions for non-i.i.d. data. See for instance https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Dependent_processes